# How to remove duplicates from array of hashes based on keys only?

Tags: ruby, hash

How would you go about removing duplicates based on the **key**?

```
values = [{"a"=>"1"}, {"a"=>"2"}, {"b"=>"1"}, {"a"=>"4"}]
```

How can I ignore the value and run `uniq` based on **key** so that it returns:

```
[{'a' => '1'}, {'b' => '1'}]
```

Comment: @sawa running 1.8.7 my **irb** accepted them just fine, but I updated the post just to make things less confusing.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Your guess is right. I am using ruby1.9.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't care which value gets clobbered, just run them into a hash (which does have unique keys and is therefore probably the right collection class for this case):

```
h = {}
values.each{|i|i.each{|k,v|h[k] = v}}
puts h # => {"a"=>"4", "b"=>"1"}
```

... or if you want the first of each key:

```
h = {}
values.each{|i|i.each{|k,v|h[k] = v unless h[k]}}
```

If you want to get back to a Array:

```
h.each{|k,v|a << {k=>v}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will work only in ruby 1.9, so it might be useless.

```
Hash[values.map(&:first).reverse].map{|a| Hash[*a]}
```

If you need it in the original order,

```
values & Hash[values.map(&:first).reverse].map{|a| Hash[*a]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without introducing any intermediate variables the following 1 liner will do the trick:

```
> [{"a"=>"1"}, {"a"=>"2"}, {"b"=>"1"}, {"a"=>"4"}].inject({}) {|s,h| s.merge(h) unless s.keys.include? h.keys}.inject([]) {|s,h| s << {h[0]=>h[1]}}
 => [{"a"=>"4"}, {"b"=>"1"}]
```